# SSRS and ignored "having" clause

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a list of data whose last update date is older than the current date minus x month.

As an example, here is a sample table :

```
|  DataGUID  |  UpdateDate   |
|------------|---------------|
|    AAA     |   12-05-2017  |
|    BBB     |   22-06-2017  |
|    AAA     |   14-02-2017  |
|    BBB     |   16-05-2017  |
```

Currently, I have a SQL request looking somewhat like the following :

```
SELECT
      DataGUID,
      MAX(UpdateDate)
FROM
      Table
GROUP BY
      DataGUID
HAVING
      MAX(UpdateDate) <= DATEADD(mm, CAST('-'+@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo AS INT), GETDATE())
ORDER BY
      MAX(UpdateDate) DESC;
```

Expected result is the following (with @LastUpdatedXMonthAgo = 1, and current date 13-07-2017) :

```
|  DataGUID  |  UpdateDate   |
|------------|---------------|
|    AAA     |   12-05-2017  |
```

It works on SSMS, but SSRS seems to ignore the "having" clause, and gives me this result :

```
|  DataGUID  |  UpdateDate   |
|------------|---------------|
|    BBB     |   22-06-2017  |
|    AAA     |   12-05-2017  |
```

Seem like SSRS just ignore the "having" clause, is there a way to make it work without using SSRS filters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are trying to prepend concatenate a hyphen to a session variable which is a number.  This is resulting in the minus sign being ignored/dropped.  Hence, your `HAVING` clause *is* working, but it is comparing each max date against one month in the future from now, instead of one month behind.

The following query will show you one way to fix this problem:

```
DECLARE @LastUpdatedXMonthAgo INT;
SET @LastUpdatedXMonthAgo = 1;
SELECT
    DATEADD(mm, CAST('-'+CAST(@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo AS VARCHAR(55)) AS INT), GETDATE());
```

This approach is to cast `@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo` to text *before* trying to "negate" the string.  Another approach would be to just make `@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo` text, but maybe this would be inconvenient for the rest of your script.

**Update:**

In SSMS, we could simplify this even further to:

```
DATEADD(mm, -@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo, GETDATE());
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: I've made ``@LastUpdatedXMonthAgo`` text, it worked, thank you.

Comment: I think it could be written more simple by having the minus before the casting like:  DATEADD(mm, - CAST(LastUpdatedXMonthAgo AS INT), GETDATE()) and if LastUpdatedXMonthAgo is int it could be written:  DATEADD(mm, -  LastUpdatedXMonthAgo  , GETDATE())

Comment: @niktrs Actually it can be written [even more simply than that](http://rextester.com/KCIC43475).

Comment: @Dremor Yes, [it does work](http://rextester.com/DWV30092), just check this demo.

Comment: In SSMS maybe, but not in SSRS, unfortunately.